# How can I populate multiple references to a model, within a nested document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a big nested document that I need to populate.

```
var PortfolioSchema = new Schema({
    bonds              :  {
        percentage          :  Number,
        USA                 :  {
            percentage           :  Number,
            treasury             :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            municipal            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            corporate            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            }
        },
        international       :  {
            percentage           :  Number,
            developed            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            emergent        :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            }
        }
    },
    stocks          :  {
        percentage          :  Number,
        USA                 :  {
            percentage           :  Number,
            largeCaps            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            mediumCaps           :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            smallCaps            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            }
        },
        international       :  {
            percentage           :  Number,
            developed            :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            },
            emergent        :  {
                percentage            :  Number,
                securities            :  [ { 
                    percentage             :  Number,
                    info                   :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'security' }
                } ]
            }
        }
    },
    _goal              :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'goal' },
    createdAt          :  { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt          :  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

How do I populate with `security` in all those fields? I've tried this code below, but it doesn't work.

```
Portfolio
    .findById(req.params.portfolio_id)
    .populate("security")
    .exec(function (err, portfolio) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).json("Portfolio not found.");
        }
        res.render('portfolios/show.ejs', {
            portfolio: portfolio
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out... All I have to do is populate each and every one of those referenced fields:

```
Portfolio
    .findById(req.params.portfolio_id)
    .populate("bonds.USA.treasury.securities.info")
    .populate("bonds.USA.municipal.securities.info")
    .populate("bonds.USA.corporate.securities.info")
    .populate("bonds.international.developed.securities.info")
    .populate("bonds.international.emergent.securities.info")
    .populate("stocks.USA.largeCaps.securities.info")
    .populate("stocks.USA.mediumCaps.securities.info")
    .populate("stocks.USA.smallCaps.securities.info")
    .populate("stocks.international.developed.securities.info")
    .populate("stocks.international.emergent.securities.info")
    .exec(function (err, portfolio) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).json("Portfolio not found.");
        }
        res.render('portfolios/show.ejs', {
            portfolio: portfolio
        });
    });
```